# Boolean filed on one column - PIVOT table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am having an issue trying to create a pivot table.  I am joining some tables and need to pivot the car model column. For example my tables are:

Person

| Id | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | Ford |
| 2 | John | Murphy |
| 3 | Cathal | Gibsey |

Cars

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Toyota |
| 2 | Ford |
| 3 | BMW |
| 4 | Hyundaii |
| 5 | Volvo |

Person-Car

| Id | Car |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

My preferred output would be the description column pivoted as columns:

| Id | FirstName | LastName | Toyota | Ford | BMW | Hyundaii | Volvo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mary | Ford | TRUE | TRUE |  |  | TRUE |
| 2 | John | Murphy |  |  | TRUE |  |  |
| 3 | Cathal | Gibsey |  |  |  | TRUE | TRUE |

My Query is:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Columncars AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

 
SELECT @Columncars= ISNULL(@Columncars + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([CDescription])
FROM (
select distinct Description [Columncars]
from Cars
) As Carsssss

 
select  @Columncars

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##CandidateCarsTable ', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE  ##CandidateCarsTable ; 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'Select distinct * into ##CandidateCarsTable 
    FROM (
     select  p.firstname, p.lastname, count(c.Id) as''carCount'',
    case when c.Description is null then ''N/A'' + N'':car '' else c.Description + N'':car ''  end as personCar
    from person p
    inner join Person-Car pc on pc.Id = p.Id
    Inner join cars c on c.Id = pc.Car
    PIVOT(MAX(carCount)
          FOR [personCar] IN (' + @ColumnCars + ')) AS PVTTable1'

    
      EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
      select * from  ##CandidateCarsTable
```

I cannot seem to get it correct.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT, My tables look perfectly find on preview and then change once saved.

[image: Preferred output table screenshot]

Comment: What is the error specifically?

Comment: @serg Ive changed it a bit now and everything comes out as NULL - updated the query

Comment: It will not run at all @Columnlanguages is not  declared. Also tag the question with your DBMS.  Looks like MS Sql Server code

Comment: @Serg I had the right column just not in this edit, I have now changed it.  Changed to sql server manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0):

This is a static sql. I quess it produces the output you want for example data. The query enumerates all possible person/car pairs and checks if the pair really exists. Change your dynamic sql building code accordingly

```
Select distinct * 
FROM (
   select firstname, lastname, [BMW],[Ford],[Hyundaii],[Toyota],[Volvo]
   from (
      select p.firstname, p.lastname, c.description, case when pc.car is not Null Then N'TRUE' end flag
      from person p 
      cross join cars c
      left join PersonCar pc on pc.Id = p.Id and c.Id = pc.Car 
   ) t
   PIVOT(MAX(flag) FOR [description] IN ([BMW],[Ford],[Hyundaii],[Toyota],[Volvo])) AS PVTTable1
   ) t;
```

Looks like the simpler version will do as unique `person.id` is included in your last edit.

```
   select id, firstname, lastname, [BMW],[Ford],[Hyundaii],[Toyota],[Volvo]
   from (
      select p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, c.description, case when pc.car is not Null Then N'TRUE' end flag
      from person p 
      left join PersonCar pc on pc.Id = p.Id 
      left join cars c on c.Id = pc.Car 
   ) t
   PIVOT(MAX(flag) FOR [description] IN ([BMW],[Ford],[Hyundaii],[Toyota],[Volvo])) AS PVTTable1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d830438701f887106f62eb965e2da0e3)